# How can I add treemaps chart and waterfall chart in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, charts, flutter-dependencies

How can I add treemap chart and waterfall chart in flutter application? Any package that giving the same feature in flutter?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the below package which has all the features you would normally expect in the treemap.
https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_treemap

And, the below package contains lots of chart types which also has waterfall chart in it.
https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_charts
https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/cartesian-charts/chart-types#waterfall-chart